# Get a list of field variables for template code

Tags: theming

For Drupal 7, how do I access (or generate) a list of all the field variables available for building a template (for a given content type)?

Some context: I used to rely on the (now deprecated) [Contemplate module](https://www.drupal.org/project/contemplate) to write my templates. Directly within its interface, it would print a list of all of the available variables, like this.

[image: contemplate]

It was quite handy. Now that I'm making disk-based templates and do not have this list generated by the Contemplate module, I'm confused as to how I might produce something similar for use as a reference.

Comment: `{{ dump() }}` will show you the available variables if you have debugging output enabled. The contemplate module did its own thing (one "magic" function called `contemplate_array_variables`) so I doubt you'll find anything quite the same. [Discovering and Inspecting Variables in Twig Templates](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/discovering-and-inspecting-variables-in-twig-templates) has some more information

Comment: Thanks @Clive ! This is a Drupal 7 site… so no Twig. Does the dump() function still work?

Comment: In your template you can always print http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php, e.g. `<?php dpm(get_defined_vars()); ?>` with the https://www.drupal.org/project/devel module installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) and then with using [get_defined_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php) you can get a list of defined variables. then in you template file use the following snippet

```
<?php
 dsm(get_defined_vars()); 
// or even  dsm(get_defined_vars()); 
?>
```

and another solution is based on  `hook_preprocess`. just dumps the variables there.

**on your template.theme file**

```
mymodule_preprocess(&$vars, $hook) {
dpm($vars);
}
```

**Update*
if you want to see the $variables on node template try on your template.

**copy/paste this snippet on your `template.php` then clear the cache**
function YOURTHEMENAME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
    dpm($variables);
    // you can add or remove whatever you want to it here
}

if your theme name is `themetastic` So

```
function themetastic_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
    dpm($variables);
    // you can add or remove whatever you want to it here
}
```

Ref: [Read this](https://github.com/jacine/theming/blob/master/advanced/preprocess-process.md) to learn more about preprocessing

Comment: Can I write this snippet into a php block and put it on a node (of a specific content type)? I tried this, and had promising results, but not exactly what I needed. It printed out what looks like the site's global variables, but not the node's field variables. Is there a way to do this without modifying the template file yet?

Comment: You'd have to do that in a preprocess hook in PHP @Sam (`dpm($variables);`). Each template is executed in its own scope, with its own bunch of available variables, so executing `get_defined_vars` will only give you something useful if you execute it directly in the template you want to find the variables for

Comment: @Sam you can do it for an specified hook. as an example. `mymodule_preprocess_block` or `mymodule_preprocess_node`.

do you how you can use those?

Comment: @YusefMohamadi Thanks! No, I don't know how to use those (but I'm Googling it now!). Any more tips here would be awesome!

Comment: @Sam do you have custom module or theme?

Comment: @YusefMohamadi Custom theme.

Comment: @Sam what is your theme name and which variables want to see ? node variables or block variables or page variables?

Comment: @YusefMohamadi Theme name: Themetastic; Content type: Static Page; Would like to see page/node variables. Thanks for your help here!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91408/discussion-between-sam-and-yusef-mohamadi).

Comment: Tested with the first option (`dsm(get_defined_vars());` in template file)… works like a champ!